# Importance Sampling for n dimensions

Tags: distributions, estimation, importance-sampling, dimensions

EDIT: I edited the question in order to make it clear.

I'm having a problem with Importance Sampling and calculation of weights in more than one dimension. Because for me this is not obvious, I will explain different scenarios, some proposed solutions and potential issues in each case. I'm hoping on not only getting some help on solving the problem but also spark discussion on it. Bare in mind that I'm a computational biologist, so there might be some statistics literature out there that answer this, but is impossible for me to understand.

Scenario 1:
My model takes as input $p_1$ and produces some prediction. This is a stochastic model and I calculate the Likelihood of the prediction given the data up to a scaling factor ($L$). In this scenario, I sample $p_1$ uniformly between $a$ and $b$ and observe a distribution of $L$ roughly normal around some value $c$. In order to compute some estimates of $p_1$, I defined the posterior distribution $P_1$ with the weighted observed density of $p_1$ by the observed $L$ (meaning that I'm given more weight to the points with high Likelihood. I want to avoid subjective thresholds and such).

Scenario 2:
My model is the same as before. However, now for some reason I did a non-uniform sample of $p_1$. I also observed that $L$ is the same independently of $L$ (this thought experiment is useful as we now what to expect from the posterior - same density for all values of $p_1$). In order to get a posterior distribution unbiased by my sampling scheme, I will compute weights $w_i = \frac{L_i}{S_i}$, where $S_1$ represents the density of my sampling distribution.

Scenario 3:
This is where it gets complex. Imagine now that my model takes as input $p_1$ and $p_2$. Again, none of the parameters is relevant for the likelihood. The sampling distribution is the following:
[image]

In case it's not easy to see, for $p_1$ there is an uniform marginal distribution but not for $p_2$

Where I see two options to build the weight vector. The first take into account the density in two dimension. The problem is that, because the points in the area of low $p_1$ have lower density in two dimensions than the ones in high $p_1$, the estimates of $p_1$ will be biased for low $p_1$.

A simple solution might be using the marginal sample distribution for each parameter to compute their statistics. For example, because the marginal distribution for $p_1$ in uniform, and the likelihood is also the same everywhere, the weights will be the same for all points and give an uniform posterior distribution for $p_1$ (GOOD)

Scenario 4:
New sampling distribution:
[image]

Now, the red dots, with low $p_1$ and high $p_2$ have a higher $L$ than the others. The problem where, when using scenario 3 solution of marginal sampling densities, is that the red dots will have an high sampling density because of the low $p_1$, low $p_2$ points. Actually, it is enough that the difference in likelihood between the red and the black dots is smaller than the difference in the marginal sampling distribution between low and high $p_1$ to make the weights on high $p_1$ higher, leading to an estimate of high $p_1$. Of course, in this case, using the two dimensional density would solve the problem (the red points have lower two dimensional density than the others)

So given all this, how can I get a solution, a way to compute the weights that allow me to get the expected results in both scenario 3 and 4? What if the number of dimensions increase further?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand.  What model is p_1 a parameter in?  What does it mean to have a simulation with a uniform distribution of p_1 (which is a single number?  how does it become a uniform distribution?)

Comment: I edit to explain further.